# onCreate savedInstanceState always null

Tags: java, android

I am using the version Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 and have simply created a new Empty Activity. After that I replaced the MainActivity with the following to test the state saving. I can observe that the state is saved with (Logcat), and I fully close down the application through Android (Logcat - PROCESS ENDED). However, I never see the onCreate savedInstanceState show anything but: 'Null pointer'.

What am I missing?

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String KEY = "Value";
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving State");

        savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY, 2);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            int val = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY, 0);
            Log.i(TAG, "OnCreate State" + Integer.toString(val));
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Null pointer");

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // get values from saved state
        int val = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY, 0);
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestore State" + Integer.toString(val));

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just rotate your device and you will see. It is not for restarts of your app. For data to survive between restarts use shared preferences.

Comment: Do you see 2 null  pointers logs or 1 in logcat?

Comment: YJR I see two, one when I bring up the application the first time. And then a second when I bring up the application for the second time.